# Магия шрифтов по умолчанию в WPF

Tags: wpf, шрифты

Я заметил, что если при создании шрифта указать пустую строку, то используется шрифт `Arial`, но он почему-то отрисовывается на несколько пикселей выше, чем `Arial`, хотя `Baseline` у них одинаковый и равен 0,921630859375. (VS2015, Windows 10)
С чем это может быть связано и как исправить такое поведение?

```
textBlock1.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"); // Red,   Baseline = 0,921630859375
textBlock2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("");      // Green, Baseline = 0,921630859375
```

[image: Шрифт "Arial" и ""]

Также заметил, что если при создании шрифта указать несуществующий шрифт, то используется уже шрифт `Segoe UI` и отрисовывается уже прилично выше, чем `Segoe UI`. Причиной тому скорей всего отличия в `Baseline`.
Почему `Baseline` отличаются? Как его можно задать вручную?

```
textBlock1.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");     // Red,   Baseline = 1,0791015625
textBlock2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("non-existent"); // Green, Baseline = 0,921630859375
```

или то же самое в XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World"
               FontSize="160"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
               Foreground="Red" />
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World"
               FontSize="160"
               FontFamily="non-existent"
               Foreground="Green" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Шрифт "Segoe UI" и "non-existent"]

Comment: Ого, ничего себе расследование!

Comment: `FontFamily=" "` в XAML генерирует снова Arial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В WPF существует механизм автоматического замещения (fallback) шрифтов. (См. [MSDN: FontFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.aspx).) Если указанный физический шрифт не удается найти на целевой системе, вместо него используется составной (composite) шрифт Global User Interface. По сути это XML-файл, который содержит параметры шрифта (в т.ч. и Baseline) и сопоставления диапазонов символов физическим шрифтам. Этот файл лежит в

> %WINDIR%\MICROSOFT.NET\Framework\версия\WPF\Fonts\GlobalUserInterface.COMPOSITEFONT

Диапазону символов 0000-052F (куда и входят английские буквы) в нем сопоставлены следующие шрифты:

> Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Simplified Arabic, Traditional Arabic, Arial
>   Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode

Параметры шрифта по умолчанию следующие:

**Baseline:** 0.9

**Line spacing:** 1.2

Таким образом, как Segoe UI, так и Arial могут, в зависимости от ситуации, замещать не найденные шрифты (при этом вид будет отличаться от соответствующих "нормальных" шрифтов, из-за отличающихся LineSpacing и BaseLine). При указании пустой строки вместо шрифта используется Arial, поскольку он прописан как NullFontFamilyCanonicalName в коде модуля [FontFamily.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/FontFamily.cs,d652308aa7fc6dd3):

```
internal static readonly CanonicalFontFamilyReference NullFontFamilyCanonicalName = CanonicalFontFamilyReference.Create(null, "#ARIAL");
```

При указании несуществующего шрифта используется Segoe UI, так как он является шрифтом по умолчанию для GUI в Windows Vista и всех более поздних ОC. См. [Change the Default Font of a WPF Application](https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2008/08/30/change-the-default-font-of-a-wpf-application/).

Если вас не устраивают параметры Composite Font по умолчанию, можно отредактировать XML-файл (там несколько секций, надо брать соответствующую вашей ОС). Но лучше, я полагаю, этого не делать, и просто не ошибаться в шрифтах.